# Skip and return objects from list of object using Lodash/Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I need to perform an operation similar to the following written in C#:

```
int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var a = items.Skip(2).Take(3);
```

Which return **3, 4 and 5**

Similarly I need to skip records from a **list of object**

```
$scope.myObject = [ { Editable: true, Name: "Daniel Test", Site: "SE100"},
                    { Editable: true, Name: "Test new", Site: "SE100"},
                    { Editable: false, Name: "Test", Site: "SE100"} ]
```

I need to **skip first record** and get back the remaining records, meaning **1-nth** record

How can I do this using lodash/underscore?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Underscore's [**first**](http://underscorejs.org/#first) and [**rest**](http://underscorejs.org/#rest) should do the trick:

```
var a = _.first( _.rest(items, 2), 3);
```

and rest on it's own can be used to skip the first record:

```
$scope.allButTheFirst = _.rest( $scope.myObject, 1)
```

Chaining can be used to make the statement slightly more pleasing to the eye and therefore improve transparency:

```
var a = _.chain(items)
    .rest(2)
    .first(3)
    .value();
```

As pointed out in @RhysvanderWaerden's answer, when using lodash use `drop` instead of `first` and `take` instead of `rest`.

Comment: If you only want to get the third item in the array and you're using chaining, do not append the `.value()`. In this case, `first()` already returns a scalar value.

Comment: If `value` is not called then the result will be an underscore wrapped object and not the value returned by the last function in the chain.

Comment: you're right, unless you call `first` without any arguments, in which case it returns the first value and not the wrapper. I haven't tested `first(1)`, but I have tested `first()`.

Comment: This does not work anymore with Lodash v4 because the ```rest()``` and ```first()``` methods expect a function! See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#rest

Comment: @rmks have clarified that this was a solution using Underscore and summarised Rhys van  der Waerden's answer in there as well to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 34):

In Lodash the `first` and `rest` functions behave differently to Underscore. Namely they do not accept a length argument. Instead `drop` and `take` should be used:

```
const a = _.take(_.drop(items, skipCount), takeCount);

// or

const a = _(items).drop(skipCount).take(takeCount).value();
```

Answer (score 21):

In [lodash v3](https://lodash.com/docs) You can use [slice](https://lodash.com/docs#slice) and [take](https://lodash.com/docs#take) methods. As alternative You can use array method [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var offset = 2;
var limit = 3;
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var result1 = _(items).slice(offset).take(limit).value();
var result2 = items.slice(offset, offset + limit);

document.getElementById('result1').innerText = result1.toString();
document.getElementById('result2').innerText = result2.toString();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  lodash v3: <span id="result1"></span>
  vanila JS: <span id="result2"></span>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

Having this

```
const skip = 0;
const take = 40;
```

You may simply do this

```
return _.slice(items, skip, skip + take);
```

Or just using native js

```
items.slice(skip, skip + take);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
/* PAGINATION WITH SORTING AND PAGING */
const page = 1;  // input page, min value 1
const limit = 2; // input limit min value 1

/* INPUT ARRAY */
const array = [
  { Editable: true,  Name: "Daniel Test", Site: "SE100"},
  { Editable: true,  Name: "Test new",    Site: "SE100"},
  { Editable: false, Name: "Test",        Site: "SE100"},
];

/* PAGINATION WITH SORTING AND PAGING */
const result = _(array)
                .orderBy(['Name'], ['asc']) // sort by ascendind
                .drop((page - 1) * limit)   // page in drop function starts from 0
                .take(limit)                // limit 2
                .value();

console.log(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
/*
  RESULT: 
  limit 2
  sort by ascendind
  [
     {
        "Editable":true,
        "Name":"Daniel Test", // name sorted by ascendind
        "Site":"SE100"
     },
     {
        "Editable":false,
        "Name":"Test",
        "Site":"SE100"
     }
  ]
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```